# Batch ERRORLEVEL results different from CMD?

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

Why does ERRORLEVEL behave differently in these two circumstances?

From the command line:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\>aescrypt.exe -v 2> NUL

C:\>echo %errorlevel%
9009
```

Versus from batch file:

```
@echo off

set /P C="> "?

set or=
if "%C%"=="a" set or=1
if "%C%"=="A" set or=1
if defined or (
    aescrypt.exe -v 2> NUL
    echo %errorlevel%
)
```

Result:

```
> a
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove you "@echo off" and see how the code is being executed.  You might find that the errorlevel in example 2 is the result of the "if defined".

Also, try this:

`@echo off`
`set /P C="> "?`
`set or=`
`if /i "%C%"=="a" set or=1`
`if not defined or goto SKIP`
`aescrypt.exe -v 2> NUL`
`echo %errorlevel%`
`:SKIP`

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed the /i flag, which was exactly what I needed. I guess my question was really "why didn't the errorlevel change when a new error occurred?" which is not a pressing issue for me. Thanks again!